# How to make gdb hit a watchpoint every time and avoid misses?

Tags: fortran, gdb, cray-pointers

The project I am working extensively uses Fortran Cray pointers. After many weeks of research, I was able to learn how to set a watchpoint on a cray pointer in gdb 7.11 for a Fortan code compiled with the intel ifort fortran compiler. Here is what I found and have been doing.

Suppose you want to set a breakpoint on a cray pointer “ro”. Get info on the variable first

```
(gdb) whatis ro
type = PTR TO -> ( REAL(8) (0:39930992,0:39931232))
```

This will tell you that the object is a pointer. Next,

```
      (gdb) print ro
      $2 = (PTR TO -> ( REAL(8) (0:39930992,0:39931232))) 0x556d93c0
```

to set the watchpoint, I next do

```
 (gdb) watch *0x556d93c0
 Hardware watchpoint 4: *0x556d93c0
```

My problem is that gdb is only stopping at certain locations (instances of `ro`) in my source although I know it appears in several other locations with the address `0x556d93c0`. How do I prevent these misses and improve accuracy of debugging?

Comment: Seriously, be glad that it works at all, Cray pointers are an esoteric extension that is long out of focus of any debugger writers.

Comment: It would be useful to know if DDT or Totalview support cray pointer debugging